# how to implement magento multisite on plesk ubunto

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento site on plesk ubuntu server and trying to create multiple sites.
I am following [this tutorial](http://dx3webs.com/front/2010/08/05/magento-multistore-setup-under-plesk/). I have created the symbolic link of folders in but it is not readable I have change its ownership and group too but still not working

Comment: Please be more specific with your problem, "but not working" is not enough information. - Include any errors messages and relevant code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Epodax i had edited this question